# Silverstripe 3.1 writable

Tags: silverstripe

Which files/folders when uploading silverstripe 3.1 on the webspace should be writable for the framework?

Its enough to mark the assets folder writable?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to upload silverstripe an you don't use the installer than yes, you just need to make `assets` write able for the webserver.

if you wish to use the silverstripe installer, there is more, but the installer will check if they are writeable and display a warning if they are not.

Comment: Thank you. What about the .htaccess file? Should it be writable to?

Comment: as said, only the assets folder.

Comment: unless you use the installer, then the .htaccess needs to be writeable. if it is not, the installer will display a message telling you to make it writeable